# Need to add up all the hours for selected column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to calculate training hours for a list of three departments but I'm not doing the query quite right. The column with the amount of hours is called tEmpCourseDetail.AuthRelTime (AuthorizedReleaseTime). But the below gives me four separate rows. What I want is it to calculate the values in all four rows.

```
SELECT SUM(AuthRelTime) AS trainingHours
FROM tEmpCourseAssoc
JOIN tEmpCourseDetail ON tEmpCourseAssoc.ECAssocID = tEmpCourseDetail.ECAssocID
WHERE AccountNumber IN ('760413','760416','767601')
GROUP BY AuthRelTime
```

[image: Here are the results]

What I want is it to return these added up. Which would be 15.

Comment: I don't know why you are group by AuthRelTime. But that is why you get 4 rows. AuthRelTime is different for. Maybe try to delete group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the group by needed at all? Try taking it out?

i.e.

```
SELECT SUM(AuthRelTime) AS trainingHours
FROM tEmpCourseAssoc
INNER JOIN tEmpCourseDetail ON tEmpCourseDetail.ECAssocID = tEmpCourseAssoc.ECAssocID
WHERE AccountNumber IN ('760413','760416','767601')
```